# Getting path to iTunes XML library without using iTunes' COM interface in C#

Tags: c#, itunes

I'm developing an app that involves reading the user's iTunes XML library. Currently, it uses this to get that path:

```
iTunesApp app = new iTunesApp();
string xmp = app.LibraryXMLPath;
```

...which results in iTunes opening when `iTunesApp` is constructed. Is there a static path to the library, or a more easier way to access it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Although I am certain they can be moved, here is what [Apple has to say](http://support.apple.com/kb/HT1660) on the topic:

> Location of the iTunes library files:
>
> Windows XP \Documents and Settings\username\My Documents\My
>   Music\iTunes\iTunes Library.xml
>
> Windows Vista \Users\username\Music\iTunes\iTunes Library.xml
>
> Windows 7 \Users\username\My Music\iTunes\iTunes Library.xml

Hope that helped...

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately No. Because the SDK is based on COM-interop, using it requires iTunes to be running. A possible Solution would be to allow iTunes to open the first time, but then save the location so that you don't have to create the object on future access.

Another option would be to make an "educated guess" on where the file is (see hd1's answer), and if none of them work, then create the com object and get the location (with iTunes open).